# Pair record with closest from join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
        id |      detected
-----------+----------------
       288 |       26817612
       288 |       26817734
       468 |       26817609
       468 |       26817646
       476 |       26817700
       502 |       26817609
       502 |       26817616
       502 |       26817655
```

and

```
        id |      fulfilled
-----------+-----------------
       288 |        26817616
       288 |        26817635
       468 |        26817623
       468 |        26817659
       476 |        26817706
       502 |        26817621
       502 |        26817627
       502 |        26817663
```

What i need to do, is to JOIN these to tables by id, matching records from the first table, with its closest fulfilled counterpart.
For example:

```
id | detected | fulfilled
-------------------------
288| 26817612 | 26817616
288| 26817734 | 26817635
468| 26817609 | 26817623
```

... and so on.

Is there any way to do this with this data, or am i wasting my time and should gather new one?

Comment: Table data doesn't look unique, you will have many to many resultset, which mean for Id: 288 you will have 4 rows as a result. So if the end results is just two rows for id 288, then your problem is incorrect. You should have unique row on that basis you could join the two dataset.

Comment: @AshishJain OP wrote that JOIN is by id but the next part correctly  would be expained  as filtering  closest matches. And it's possible to get double records even after filtering - if there are 2 pairs of records with the same distance

Comment: Of course you can do that if you split processing in stages: a) join by `id`, b) calculating min distances between `MIN(ABS(detected - fullfilled) .. GROUP BY id`, c) filtering joined data from step `a`  by values calculated on step `b`. If you create [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) - you will get your answer quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a solution at DB fiddle with just dataset for Id 288 and it should work for all other Id's as well. Here is the URL https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vieqapnXDrrGzGeUA7GE5h/4

Here is final sql:

```
SELECT 
    s1.Id, s1.detected, s2.fulfilled
FROM 
(SELECT 
    t1.Id, t1.detected, MIN(ABS(t1.detected - t2.fulfilled)) AS Diff
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN 
    table2 t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id
Group by t1.Id, t1.detected) s1
LEFT JOIN
table2 s2
ON s1.Id = s2.Id
WHERE 
   s1.Diff = ABS(s1.detected - s2.fulfilled)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to reduce the number of rows as well.  To me, this suggests `row_number()`:

```
select t12.*
from (select t1.*, t2.*fulfilled
             row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by abs(t1.detected - t2.fulfilled)) as seqnum
      from t1 join
           t2
           on t1.id = t2.id
     ) t12
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you have, assuming both tables will always contain the same list of `id` values, is to use `apply()` and subtract the two values to get the closest match:

```
select *
from t1
cross apply(
    select top (1) t2.fulfilled
    from t2
    where t2.id=t1.id
    order by Abs(t1.detected-t2.fulfilled)
)t2
```